# How to change frame of UIImageView on subclassed UICollectionViewCell in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have these line of code in my didSelectItemAtIndexPath method:

```
var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParallaxCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "8")
```

I can change the content of the imageView of the selected cell. What I want to change though is the frame of the imageView. All settings to that get ignored however. Does anyone know why?

Comment: are you using autolayout? because if you are, the autolayout constraints will override any changes you do in code.

Comment: Sounds like autolayout alright.